# Webshims lib with durandal updatePolyfill

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, polyfills, webshim

I am trying to use Webshims lib in my durandal based SPA. Followed instructions on WebShims lib web site, included custom modernizr, jquery and the polyfill. All works great so long as the controls are not loaded dynamically either by knockout or durandal transitioning in the views.

Going through the web site for Webshims, it mentions something like this

If a plugin, script or framework is used, which uses a "normal" JS/jQuery manipulation method instead of the corresponding webshims enhanced manipulation method to generate new HTML5 content (i.e.: .html() instead of .htmlPolyfill()), the method .updatePolyfill() can be used to polyfill the dynamic content:

```
 $('#my-dynamic-container').load('ajax/test.html', function(){
     $(this).updatePolyfill();
 });
```

I am trying to see the best possible place to do this. I obviously do not want to touch durandal's modules. Either I extend one, or get a hook in to a place when the html is loaded. Anyone else try to do this? Pointers? directions? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give Durandal's `viewAttached` live cycle event (http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/) a try. At the point it fires `view` is attached to the parent element, but not necessarily to the DOM yet. This might or might be sufficient for `updatePolyfill()` to work.

```
viewAttached: function (view){
    $(view).updatePolyfill();
}
```

Comment: If I understand this right, this will be from the shell.js right?

Comment: I'm afraid you've to set this in every model that you're using in a Durandal compose http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/. If the only one that you're using right now is shell.js then yes.

Comment: I have actually added it to viewModelBinder.afterBind in the main.js. It seems to work fine. The only issue I can see is it taking a long time to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:
If you are using a parent view which has a child view in a "wizard" style where you dynamically change things from the parent view Step1 Step2 Step3...this will not work because viewAttached() only fires on the parent once... and unfortunately viewAttached() on a child views runs before the DOM is created (put a break in) you can physically see there is no DOM on child viewAttached()

This is a bit of a problem :(

The only workaround i could use was a custom KO binding to the elements i needed custom javascript to run and run it within that binding, but still this is an issue.